# CallIntMethod result -1 - ANDROID JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to use the ANDROID SharedPreferences from C.
For easier usage, I've a class and some methods for it (getIniParamInt, getIniParamString etc.) The things works fine in JAVA.

The  problem is, if I call the method from jni it sends back -1 to C.
Parts of my JAVA code (simplified for test, SharedPref. removed etc.):

```
public class IniManipulate {
   public int getIniParamInt(String mezoNev)
                  {return 999;}  // settings.getInt("abc", -9999);
```

C code:

```
const char* paramOut 
paramOut = "abc";
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls1,"getIniParamInt","(Ljava/lang/String;)I");
     if (mid == NULL) {cDebug1 = 888;return; }
jstring* parameter = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, paramOut);
     if (parameter == NULL) {return;}
jint paramInt = (jint) (*env)->CallIntMethod(env,thiz, mid, parameter);
cDebug1 = (int)paramInt;
```

Always returns with paramInt=-1; instead of 999;

I've already digged up the whole web and I couldn't find the solution.
Could you please help me, what's wrong with the CallIntMethod calling?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I found the SOLUTION!
The problem is, in Java code:
It must declare the called method as private method instead of public!!!

```
private int getIniParamInt(String mezoNev)
              {return 999;}
```

I'm a beginner, so I don't know the real explanation... I just tried it.
I hope it's helpful for people who wants use method like this.