# JNI CallIntMethod from c++ returns wrong value

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

im using JNI to embed some Java-Panels in my (ancient, VC6) MFC-Application. When I invoke CallIntMethod for some testmethod in the Java-Class i dont get the expected value.

Maybe a similar question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382106/random-values-when-retrieving-jint-value-using-jni) , but there is no solution for my problem, so i asked a new question.

My code looks as follows:

**JAVA:**

```
public int int_test()
{
    return 22;
}
```

**C++:**

```
jmethodID testmethod = env->GetMethodID(clsBean, "int_test", "()I");
if (testmethod)
{
    // this one gets me some random number
    jint val = env->CallIntMethod(clsBean, testmethod);
    int a = (int)val; 
}
```

**EDIT (regarding answer from mkaes):**

this

```
jint val = env->CallIntMethod(clsBean, testmethod);
```

calls this method declared in *jni.h:*

```
jint CallIntMethod(jobject obj, jmethodID methodID, ...) {
    va_list args;
    jint result;
    va_start(args,methodID);
    result = functions->CallIntMethodV(this,obj,methodID,args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

and ends up in a call to this:

```
jint (JNICALL *CallIntMethodV)
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jmethodID methodID, va_list args);
```

so i thought this **jobject obj** is my reference to the Java-Class and **jmethodID methodID** the reference to the function to call. Sorry but i dont get what jobject i got to pass in if not the reference to the Java-Class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CallIntMethod result -1 - ANDROID JNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253389/callintmethod-result-1-android-jni)

Comment: i read this question already but the provided answer did not help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not use an object for your class.

`jmethodID testmethod = env->GetMethodID(clsBean, "int_test", "()I");`
 `clsBean` is the class ID.

`jint val = env->CallIntMethod(clsBean, testmethod);`
The second parameter needs to be the object your calling this method on. Unless you change your method to be static.
Then you can use `CallStaticIntMethod`

Comment: thx, got it! *GetMethodID* gest the method from the class, then you can call *CallIntMethod* on an **INSTANCE** of that class. thx alot for the hint